# Why isn't AWS Elastic Beanstalk finding my composer.json file?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a composer.json file in my root project directory but `eb` isn't finding it and says I didn't include a `composer.json` file:

```json
{
    "msg": "Instance deployment: You didn't include a 'composer.json' file in your source bundle. The deployment didn't install Composer dependencies.",
    "timestamp": 1112232342,
    "severity": "INFO"
}
```

I logged into the server and checked to see if the file exists and it does. It's located in `/var/www/html/project_name/composer.json`

Any help/guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you specify Document root folder in your .ebextensions file?

Comment: No. The docs don't specify that I have to have this, or atleast they don't on this page https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/php-configuration-composer.html